Javascript promises: Why does return in nested then chain change result order?
I'm new to JS Promises and am trying to understand why I get different results depending on if I have a return or not on this line: return foo(2).then(() => {


function foo(num) {
  console.log(num)
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, num * 1000));
}

foo(1).then(() => {
  return foo(2).then(() => {
    console.log(4)
  });
}).then(() => {
  foo(3)
})



vs


function foo(num) {
  console.log(num)
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, num * 1000));
}

foo(1).then(() => {
  foo(2).then(() => {
    console.log(4)
  });
}).then(() => {
  foo(3)
})



Why does the order of 4/3 change?

with return you are chaining promises, without return you are just executing some code in the outer then. You may read: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Calling .then(someFn) creates a new promise. That promise will resolve to whatever someFn returns. If someFn returns undefined, as in your second example, then the new promise can resolve to undefined right away. If someFn returns a promise, as in your first example, then it must wait for the inner promise to resolve, before the outer promise knows what value it's supposed to resolve with.
In short: if you return an inner promise, you force the outer promise to wait for it.

The difference in behavior is due to how promises chain and return values.
INNTER PROMISE RETURN


function foo(num) {
  console.log(num);
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, num * 1000));
}

foo(1).then(() => {
  return foo(2).then(() => {
    console.log(4);
  });
}).then(() => {
  foo(3);
});



foo(1) starts and prints 1. It returns a promise that resolves after 1 second, After 1 second, the first then is called. It returns the promise from foo(2). foo(2) starts and prints 2. It returns a promise that resolves after 2 seconds. After 2 seconds, the inner then prints 4.
The outer then waits for the inner then to complete because the inner promise was returned. After the inner promise resolves, the outer then execut.
FinallSy, foo(3) starts and prints 3.
NOT RETURNING INNER PROMISE


function foo(num) {
  console.log(num);
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, num * 1000));
}

foo(1).then(() => {
  foo(2).then(() => {
    console.log(4);
  });
}).then(() => {
  foo(3);
});



foo(1) starts and prints 1. It returns a promise that resolves after 1 second After 1 second, the first then is called, foo(2) starts and printss 2. It returns a promises that resolves after 2 seconds, but this promise is not returneded to the outer then. The outer then doesn't wait for foo(2) to complete and proceeds immediately . foo(3) starts and prints 3 after the first promise resolves, without waiting for foo(2) to complete. After 2 seconds from the start of foo(2), the inner then printss 4.
by returning the Inner Promise The outer then waits for the inner promise to resolve before proceeding. so that foo(3) runs after both foo(1) and foo(2) complete. when not returning the Inner promise The outer then doesn’t wait for the inner promise to resolve, so foo(3) runs as soonn as foo(1) completes, independently of foo(2).
